# Is it possible to extend emergency activity with more features?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have idea to extend emergency activity to add some personal data information in case of losing your phone (this is that screen when you are unlock phone and in the bottom there is an option to fast call for e.g: 911 or 112).
Is it possible to make it in not hard way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make it in not hard way?

If downloading the Android source code, modifying this activity, packaging the result in a ROM mod, and installing it on Android devices is a "hard way", then, no, it is not possible "to make it in not hard way".

For starters, Android SDK applications cannot dial emergency numbers, so even if you were able to some intercept and replace this activity, you could not do what the activity is supposed to do.

Also, bear in mind that showing "some personal data information in case of losing phone" is already implemented in Android itself, at least for Android 4.x. You can set the personal information in the Settings app.

Comment: I have phone with android 2.3.3 Thanks, I didn't know about this in 4.x